# UIStackView : Is it really necessary to call both removeFromSuperView and removeArrangedSubview to remove a subview?

Tags: ios, uistackview

From the [UIStackView Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIStackView_Class_Reference/)

In removeArrangedSubview:

> To prevent the view from appearing on screen after calling the stack’s removeArrangedSubview: method, explicitly remove the view from the subviews array by calling the view’s removeFromSuperview method.

In arrangedSubview:

> Whenever an arranged view’s removeFromSuperview method is called, the stack view removes the view from its arrangedSubview array

From these, it seems that calling just removeFromSuperview is enough to remove a subview and I've been using it like that without problems. I also confirmed the behavior by logging the count of the arrangedSubviews array when removeFromSuperview is called.

A lot of tutorials and comments here on S/O however, say to call both. Is there a reason for this? Or do people just do it because the documentation says so?

Comment: Not a proper answer for you, but an anecdote: I was only calling `removeArrangedSubview` without knowing I was supposed to also call `removeFromSuperview`, and it was indeed clearing the view from `arrangedSubviews` but the view was still appearing in `subviews` causing all kinds of confusing breakage. Adding the `removeFromSuperview` call (once I saw this question!) resolved it.

Comment: I don't know the answer, either. But I was having an issue where all my subviews were not being removed after using RemoveArrangedSubview. After seeing this post, I added removeFromSuperview calls and now it works as expected.

Comment: The documentation seems to suggest that you only need to call `removeFromSuperview`. I'm only calling `removeFromSuperview` without any issues.

Comment: Seems there is a problem with IOS12 by just calling removeArrangedSubview. It's not removing the view properly. Calling just removeFromSuperview works.

Comment: Calling removeArrangedSubview is not sufficient to remove the target subview from view hierarchy, as iOS 15, this is still the case.

Answer (score 113):

No, just call `subview.removeFromSuperview()`

> ```
> /* Removes a subview from the list of arranged subviews without removing it as
>  a subview of the receiver.
>     To remove the view as a subview, send it -removeFromSuperview as usual;
>  the relevant UIStackView will remove it from its arrangedSubviews list
>  automatically.
>  */
> open func removeArrangedSubview(_ view: UIView)
> ```

Comment: Actually this is an incorrect interpretation. Just using `removeFromSuperView()` appears to work, but can cause weird crashes if you are adding and removing a lot of views. If you read the discussion part of the docs it's pretty clear you have to call both.

Comment: @drekka can you cite your source, or provide a link? The doc seems clear about not needing both calls.

Comment: I can confirm this, I have crash reports from my app when calling `removeFromSuperview()` only. I will be releasing an update shortly which also adds `removeArrangedSubview()` and report back on whether this fixes it!

Comment: @simonthumper did it fix it?

Comment: I was removing 2 buttons from stackView with removeArrangedSubview and I still had them after remove (only the frame was modified). after using 
func removeArrangedView(_ view: UIView) {
        removeArrangedSubview(view)
        view.removeFromSuperview()
    }
everything is good :)

Answer (score 41):

In iOS 12.0, You need to use

```
stackView.arrangedSubviews[index].removeFromSuperview()
```

If you use `removeArrangedSubview`, there is a bug where the view at the specified index removed, but the view I want to clear appears at `CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)`.

Hope this help someone.

Comment: Having this issue 2. Where abouts is the big log for this?

Answer (score 15):

Hacking With Swift provides a pretty good example and explanation, using Web views in this case.

> The reason is that you can remove something from a stack view's arranged subview list then re-add it later, without having to recreate it each time – it was hidden, not destroyed. We don't want a memory leak, so we want to remove deleted web views entirely. If you find your memory usage ballooning, you probably forgot this step!

https://www.hackingwithswift.com/read/31/4/removing-views-from-a-uistackview-with-removearrangedsubview

Comment: hackingwithswift was updated to also only recommend `removeFromSuperview`

Answer (score 14):

To remove a arrangedSubview from a stackview is

```
// To remove it from the view hierarchy
   subView.removeFromSuperview()
```

Comment: `removeFromSuperview()` is enough, according to Apple‘s documentation and as you can also easily test yourself. `removeArrangedSubview()` is simply not necessary.

Comment: Calling removeArrangedSubview() only, actually will leave the view alive in the view hierarchy. It is a bug cost hours to debug, only when by dumping and checking the view hierarchy, I found the removed subview, is still in the view hierarchy, which is weird.

Answer (score 8):

You're right, just the call to `removeFromSuperview` is sufficient to have the view fully removed.

I suspect the reason for people putting both is because they run across the `removeArrangedSubview` documentation which seems to say both are needed. (And indeed, they are, if you call `removeArrangedSubview` and want the view really gone.)

The additional doc in `arrangedSubviews` is not seen by so many, so they don't realize `removeArrangedSubview` is, in this case, optional.

Comment: As I said in a comment above, it may appear to work, but can trigger crashes. So just using `removeFromSuperview()` is not recommended.

Answer (score 8):

No, To remove specific view.

```
func removeArrangedSubview(_ view: UIView)
```

To remove all subviews

```
stackView.arrangedSubviews.forEach { $0.removeFromSuperview() }
```

Comment: The 2 lines are using different subview removal methods, thus are not doing the same. In some iOS versions `removeArrangedSubview` is not correct. You need to consistently call `removeFromSuperview`, which is the single call that works consistently, according to Apple doc and what all the others write here.

Answer (score 4):

For removing i use this extension. Don't really know is it necessary to remove constraints. But maybe it would help.

```
extension UIStackView {
    func removeAllArrangedSubviews() {
        let removedSubviews = arrangedSubviews.reduce([]) { (allSubviews, subview) -> [UIView] in
            self.removeArrangedSubview(subview)
            return allSubviews + [subview]
        }

        for v in removedSubviews {
            if v.superview != nil {
                NSLayoutConstraint.deactivate(v.constraints)
                v.removeFromSuperview()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is fine as long as the view removed is destroyed immediately. But there is a potential bug if it is reused - all the internal constraint have been removed so it will likely not layout correctly

Answer (score 2):

I will suggest get arranged subviews then remove it like below code .

```
for view in self.stackView.arrangedSubviews{
      self.stackView.removeArrangedSubview(view)
      view.removeFromSuperview()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer: **NO**! (as previously stated by many others)

##### Longer answer:

```swift
// to remove "view" from the stack entirely 
// calls removeArrangedSubview()
view.removeFromSuperview()
```

```swift
// to add "view" to the stack
// calls addSubview()
stackView.addArrangeSubview(view)
```

Please check out the explicit paragraph in Apple's documentation about this issue (`Maintain consistency between the arranged views and subview`):
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uistackview#1653129

Here is the important part:

> The stack view ensures that its arrangedSubviews property is always a subset of its subviews property. Specifically, the stack view enforces the following rules:
> When the stack view adds a view to its arrangedSubviews array, it also adds that view as a subview, if it isn’t already.
> When a subview is removed from the stack view, the stack view also removes it from the arrangedSubviews array.
> Removing a view from the arrangedSubviews array doesn’t remove it as a subview. The stack view no longer manages the view’s size and position, but the view is still part of the view hierarchy, and is rendered on screen if it’s visible.